# Observable.Observable.of is not a function - not resolved by changing import statement

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs, rxjs5

```
LoginComponent.html:18 ERROR TypeError: Observable.Observable.of is not a function
at LogConsole.webpackJsonp../node_modules/angular-logger/angular-logger.umd.js.LogConsole.log (angular-logger.umd.js:142)
at LogService.webpackJsonp../node_modules/angular-logger/angular-logger.umd.js.LogService.writeToLog (angular-logger.umd.js:351)
at LogService.webpackJsonp../node_modules/angular-logger/angular-logger.umd.js.LogService.fatal (angular-logger.umd.js:311)
at LoginComponent.webpackJsonp../src/app/user/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.hi (login.component.ts:83)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginComponent.html:18)
at handleEvent (core.js:13254)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14739)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14326)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:9703)
at core.js:10317
```

I'm getting this error in the app consuming my custom logger library.

login.component.ts:

```
    hi(){
    alert('hi!');
    this.logService.fatal('hi there!');
}
```

which ends up calling the following function in my custom logger library, which is the cause of the error:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { LogPublisher } from './log-publisher.class';
import { LogEntry } from './log-entry.class';

export class LogConsole extends LogPublisher {

log(record: LogEntry) : Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(record.buildLogString());

    return Observable.of(true);
}

}
```

I tried changing the import url for the 'of' operator, with no success.

The rxjs version in the custom logger library is

```
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "~5.5.0"
  }
```

and the version in the consuming app is:

```
"rxjs": "~5.5.0"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the newer version of invoking Rxjs  methods:

```
import {of}                 from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

and then :

```
 return of(true);
```

**Update rxjs version 6:**

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```